# Why is c.vim overriding .vimrc for HTML?

Tags: vim, indentation

My `~/.vimrc` contains the following (default in Ubuntu 14.04, just added the last line):

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

filetype plugin indent on
```

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 noexpandtab
```

---

I was expecting for only `.c` and `.h` files to use 8-column tabs. However, other files are also being afected such as `.html` files.

How can I make `c.vim` affect only C-related files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 noexpandtab
```

to this:

```
setlocal tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 noexpandtab
```

Comment: Changing `set` to `setlocal` worked! Side note: made another change now, removed `filetype plugin indent on` and placed `c.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax/c.vim`.

Comment: No, keep `filetype plugin indent on`. Vim is useless as a programming editor without that line.

Comment: And don't move this file to `syntax/`. `ftplugin/` is the right place.

Comment: Will do! The indentation was working without it but I'll keep it.

Comment: "`smartindent`" is old and deprecated, filetype-specific indenting is much better. You should remove `set smartindent`.